# Brackets startup is very slow due to opening in root folder

Tags: osx-yosemite, adobe-brackets

The title pretty much states it. When I open brackets it opens with the root folder "/" by default and it takes some time before it fails indexing files:

[image]

I can get it to work, if I wait long enough, but is a most annoying issue. Is there some way I can change the startup folder or something?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **File > Open Folder...** to select the folder that contains the project or files that you want to work with, then close Brackets, and restart it.

Brackets will restart using the folder that you selected, and its structure will be shown on the left side of the screen. That's really all there is to it.

One other thing that might impact startup time is leaving a lot of files open when closing Brackets, since Brackets will reopen all those files when it is restarted. Your open files are listed under **Working Files** in the top left of the screen.

Comment: That's the odd thing, I did try that! But every time it still opens with the root folder.

Comment: It looks like your preferences are not being saved for some reason. The folder Brackets uses on startup is defined in file state.json. Other users have reported problems with that file becoming corrupted. For example, see https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/9880 and https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/8241. Try deleting (or just renaming) your state.json file while Brackets is closed, then restart Brackets to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Where is that located? Should it be in the app package? I can't find it

Comment: On Windows the file is named C:/Users/{user}/AppData/Roaming/Brackets/state.json (and file brackets.json should also be in that folder). I don't know about OSX though. If you don't have an instance of state.json then perhaps there is an installation issue, and reinstalling Brackets may fix your problem?